# Allow protected variables in Java for SonnarQube

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Is there any option to change SonnarQube check style (plugin sonnar-runner for Gradle) to allow using protected variables in Java?

I don't wanna discuss about using protected variables but I have on SonarQube site issues that I have protected variable instead of private.

Is there any option to turn off only this type of notification?

Comment: You need to adjust the used RuleSet in Sonar to allow protected variables.

Comment: There is any option for do this from gradle script site? Of course I already contact with my admin to change it but there is an option to set the rules directly in gradle script?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gradle, but I strongly doubt that Gradle can overwrite Sonar rules. The rules in Sonar are bound to the project, so Gradle would need to reconfigure the whole Sonar project for each run, which would be time/performance consuming and not approtiate.
The correct way is to reconfigure the RuleSet within the Sonar project. This would be done once, all following Gradle builds would then use the new rule configuration and not mark protected variables anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize rules in SonarQube, just read the ["Configuring Rules" documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Rules).